# Android urlConnection Posting do not write to outputstream

Tags: java, android, json

I have an Application in Android, that Use REST Webservice as main data input, I use 2 types of webservice, one for GET which is working normally, and one for POST which I have a problem on it, 
As I spent 2 days to find the problem , it is the writing to the urlConnection object that I created, but I don't know why all my tries to make url accept the strings I need to post failed, so what is the wrong in the code below? 
NOTE: the webservice is not JSON but html response page with JSON object inside. 
NOTE2: the parameters are regular strings like "name=etc".
this is the code used in URlConnection in my Class :

```
try {
        URL httpurl = new URL(BasicConstants.BASE_URL + urlAddress);
        if (MethodType == 1) {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) httpurl.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + "UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            OutputStream output = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(params.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        TheResponse = readStream(in);
        // disconnect the connection when finished.
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        TheResponse = e.toString();
        return TheResponse;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        TheResponse = e.toString();
        return TheResponse;
    }
    // will always return data in html format, so decode it using Html class
    return  Html.fromhtml(Html.fromHtml(TheResponse)).toString();

}
```

EDIT:
My question is : is there something wrong in the code above? 
why using it only return blank page that has 200 response code with no errors (I cannot know what is the error exactly from android or from webservice) 
but I notice something, if you use this code above in posting, you will see only the url but cannot see the parameters written in the urlConnection. 
So I need to make sure that I didn't miss something in the code of post above.

Comment: How is this PHP or Classic ASP?

Comment: Classic ASP actually

Comment: But there's no Classic ASP or PHP code there, and no contextual mention of it in your post.

Comment: The Question is weather there is an error in Android code for returning post or not, the webservice is written in asp.net

Comment: what's the problem? Are you getting an error or something? Add that to your question. Without this, we have no clue whatsoever.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried alot in answering the question and waited too long but now I found a solution which I think it is not the best solution, but solve my issue :

I used the new urlConnection method in my question, which I need to maintain because the application will be used from API 17 and more, but in this situation I had to use the httpGet from older methods (I thought it is depreciated, but found the gradle to use )

.. first to import in your gradle file :

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

// second using the code below: 
    /*post operation */

```
 class doProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Context mcontext;
        private String urlToPost;

        public doProcess(Context mcontext, String urlToPost) {
            this.mcontext = mcontext;
            this.urlToPost = urlToPost;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String responseString = "";


            try {

                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost getRequest = new HttpPost(urlToPost);
                HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);

                final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                //200
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                    return null;

                }
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlToPost);

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity("", "UTF-8");

                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));


                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(getResponse.getEntity());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return responseString;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if (aVoid.isEmpty()) {

            } else {
                UtilityFunctions.getFunctions().makeToast(mcontext, Html.fromHtml(aVoid.toString()).toString());
            }

     }
    }
```

and the url is completely string e.g: (www.example.com/asap.asp?username=name&password=pass&operation=operation)

But this is a temporary solution, I want a permanent one that used in [urlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)